# How to start/stop/restart launchd services from the command line?

Tags: mac-osx, service, osx-leopard, launchd

How do I restart, say for example my httpd or afpd, running any Mac OS X >= 10.5 (Leopard-), without having to use the GUI and go to *System Preferences -> Sharing* and unchecking/checking "Web Sharing"?

I'm looking for the canonical equivalent to Debian's `invoke-rc.d apache2 restart`.

EDIT: The question is about **launchd controlled services in general**, not specifically Apache (-which was simply an example).

Comment: From the answers so far, is correct to assume there is no single launchctl command to *restart* a service?

Comment: @JS. According to the manual page, `kickstart` together with the `-k` option seems to do the trick.  See my answer below ...

Answer (score 214, accepted):

launchctl(8) is your friend.  Just keep in mind that some of the services (sshd for example) are disabled in the configuration file so you will need to use the `-w` switch when loading them.  Here is a sshd example:

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

You can stop the service using the `unload` subcommand.

```
$ sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

To list the services, as you might have already guessed use the 'list' subcommand ;)

Comment: In addition, `launchctl list` does not complain but does not show everything, `sudo launchctl list` is needed for that.

Comment: It's not that it doesn't show everything, it shows a completely different list.  When you run `launchctl` as a normal user, it shows/manages LaunchAgents running in your user session; run as root, it shows/manages the system-wide LaunchDaemons.

Comment: I can see "com.openssh.sshd" in that list, so I guess that config is "loaded". Now, how come for example `sudo launchctl start com.openssh.sshd` doesn't do *anything*, not evan fail with an error message, even less so actually launch anything?

Comment: @conny: you need to load the service first before starting it, this is what the load subcommand do. Contrary to the what you may one expect, one cannot start a service that hasn't been loaded yet.  Once a service is loaded one can use 'stop' and 'start' subcommands to stop/start the service.  To make sure the service is no longer running use the 'remove' command ('unload' would do that too) -- this will unload the service and any future 'launchctl start' commands will silently fail.  Hope that helps.

Comment: It always seemed quite unintuitive to me that something could be "loaded" while at the same time "stopped". I guess it will make sense, eventually :)

Comment: @conny It might be confusing in the general case, however when you are writing a service and you suspect for example that something nasty is happening on startup, you can load it once and the use 'stop'/'start' to debug the issue.

Comment: Why no mention of `launchctl start <label>` or `launchctl stop <label>`? If it's already started by launchctl there's no need to reload the plist file (unless it changed as well?). It is annoying there is no `restart` or `reload` command. Anyone know of a single-command way of making (for example) mongod pick up a config file change? I'm just not satisfied with `... stop ... && ... start ...`.

Comment: I get `sudo: launchctl: command not found` in Sierra.

Answer (score 27):

To restart a service, you can use the `launchctl kickstart` command, together with the `-k` option.  For example, to restart apache, you can use

```
sudo launchctl kickstart -k system/org.apache.httpd
```

This information is from the `launchctl` manual page:

> ```
>  kickstart [-kp] service-target
>           Instructs launchd to run the specified service immediately, regardless of its
>           configured launch conditions.
>
>           -k       If the service is already running, kill the running instance before
>                    restarting the service.
>           [...]
> ```

Comment: When I tried this my service had hung, it did not stop after a short wait, "kill" on the pid did not help, doing "kill -9" on the pid killed the process and let kickstart (that had been running in another console while I tried to kill the process) continue and start the service again. I did not wait for very long before starting to kill things manually, so waiting long enough might have been enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 18):

You could simply do

```
sudo launchctl stop com.openssh.sshd
```

If you don't known the full service name, you can do

```
sudo launchctl list
```

If you still don't find the service you expected, try to run without the root identity:

```
launchctl list
```

And you don't need to unload and load service.

Comment: I tried this and now I can't use `ssh` from my Mac. Rebooting doesn't fix. Replacing `stop` with `start` also doesn't fix.

Comment: I tried this and I still can ssh to my Mac!

Comment: @dmitriy-apollonin It does not work, you must use `sudo unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` instead.

Comment: The question is about restarting a service, but I don't think that `launchctl stop` does restart a service.

Answer (score 7):

sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for `launchctl`.

```
SYNOPSIS
 launchctl [subcommand [arguments ...]]

DESCRIPTION
 launchctl interfaces with launchd to load, unload daemons/agents and gen-
 erally control launchd.  launchctl supports taking subcommands on the
 command line, interactively or even redirected from standard input.
 These commands can be stored in $HOME/.launchd.conf or /etc/launchd.conf
 to be read at the time launchd starts.
```

Comment: But reading the man-page does not tell me what the equivalent of either `invoke-rc.d my-little-daemon restart` is ... It refers to "job_label" but does not tell me how to list the "job_label"s available.

Comment: I think nayden's response has got this covered.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if you are looking for `launchctl reload`, you can define shell function in your `~/.bashrc/.zshrc` as I did:

```
function lctl {
    COMMAND=$1
    PLIST_FILE=$2
    if [ "$COMMAND" = "reload" ] && [ -n "$PLIST_FILE" ]
      then
        echo "reloading ${PLIST_FILE}.."
        launchctl unload ${PLIST_FILE}
        launchctl load ${PLIST_FILE}
      else
        echo "either command not specified or plist file is not defined"
    fi
}
```

Command execution looks like -> `lctl reload <your-plist-name>.plist`

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Works with other OSses as well as it is part of Apache.

Comment: Even though the topic doesn't mention apache in particular, I should have anticipated this interpretation.... I'm sorry, but that was not what I was looking for :)

Comment: Ok, I catched the httpd part, for which using apachectl is the easier variant :)

Answer (score 0):

For restarting, I think the easiest way is to kill the process. Assume you have configured keepalive, which most daemon processes do. `pkill apache2` will do. Then the process will start again by itself.

Comment: Find the process `ps -ef | grep <servicename>` then restart this process with `sudo kill -HUP <pid of service>`. You can check that the pid has changed. I find this great when working with services that are ported directly from linux that do not show up in launchctl

Answer (score -1):

There is a small & useful app for this named Lingon.
[Lingon freeware edition is here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lingon/) 
sometimes restarting a service can be tricky.

```
syslog -w
```

reading helps though.